# Thymeleaf - different amount of parameters

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have this form:

```
<form th:action="@{'/articles/' + ${article.id} + '/processTest'}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr th:each="entry,iter: ${wordsWithTranslation}">
            <td><input type="text" th:value="${entry.key.value}" th:name="'q' + ${iter.index}" readonly="readonly"/>
            </td>
            <td> -----</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:name="'a' + ${iter.index}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Sprawdź"/>
</form>
```

wordsWithTranslation is a HashMap which can contain different amount of elements.

And the controller:

```
public String processTest(Model model, @PathVariable Long id, 
@ModelAttribute(value = "q0") String q0, 
@ModelAttribute(value = "a0") String a0, 
@ModelAttribute(value = "q1") String q1,
@ModelAttribute(value = "a1") String a1)
```

how can I fix that method parameters to not do something like that (ModelAttribute for every q and a value)? Is there any way to do something like loop here or what is the best solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set names of inputs as names of array params:

```
<form th:action="@{'/articles/' + ${article.id} + '/processTest'}" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr th:each="entry : ${wordsWithTranslation}">
            <td>
                <input type="text" th:value="${entry.key.value}" name="q[]" readonly="readonly"/>
            </td>
            <td> -----</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="a[]"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Sprawdź"/>
</form>
```

Now in controller you can accept this fields as `List<>` or `array`:

```
@RequestMapping(value='/articles/{id}/processTest')
public String someMethod(Model model, @PathVariable Long id, 
                         @RequestParam(value = "q[]") List<String> qList,
                         @RequestParam(value = "a[]") List<String> aList){
    ...
}
```

Every item of list `q` will correspond to some item of list `a`.

Comment: It works with RequestParam, but with ModelAttribute not. There is only 1 element in qList and 0 in aList.

Comment: @Helosze `@ModelAttribute` does nothing for bind parameters. This annotation just indicates that parameter of method should be added to the model with specified name. You can remove `@ModelAttribute` at all, but values will be bound anyway.